# Is there any suggestion for implementing Dynamic client registration using Oauth2 and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am working on a module where we need to register different applications consuming our services as client and assign them unique client id and client secret.

I need to generate jwt tokens when client id and client secret is valid

I am not aware about the approach how to proceed with it. So, I need your suggestions for same.

Comment: Are you deploying your Identity Provider from Spring Boot or you are using some other solutions like CAS, Keycloak, Auth0 etc.?

Comment: I am using Spring Boot, spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 and JWT for generating token along with JPA